# Use process substitution as input file to Python twice

Tags: python, linux, process-substitution

Consider the following python script

```
#test.py
import sys
inputfile=sys.argv[1]
with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line

with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line
```

Now I want to run `test.py` on a substituted process, e.g.,

```
python test.py <( cat file | head -10)
```

It seems the second `f.readlines` returns empty. Why is that and is there a way to do it without having to specify two input files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Why is that.

  - Process substitution works by creating a named pipe. So all the data consumed at the first open/read loop.
- Is there a way to do it without having to specify two input files.

  - How about buffering the data before using it.

Here is a sample code

```
import sys
import StringIO
inputfile=sys.argv[1]

buffer = StringIO.StringIO()

# buffering
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    buffer.write(f.read())

# use it 
buffer.seek(0)
for line in buffer:
    print line

# use it again
buffer.seek(0)
for line in buffer:
    print line
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. My problem is that the substituted process is enormous in size (12gb). Thus buffering may not be ideal. In fact my bash command was killed halfway by the os. So I had to settle with saving an intermediate file in the hard drive.

Comment: AFAIK, if the amount data produced by the substituted process is bigger than consumed data in your program, It doesn't work. [ref](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer). It can be a good solution to use an intermediate file. Or if the data is sequence-independent, using thread or multiprocess can be a good solution, too.

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` will read all available lines from the input at once. This is why the second call returns nothing because there is nothing left to read. You can assign the result of `readlines()` to a local variable and use it as many times as you want:

```
import sys
inputfile=sys.argv[1]
with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line

    #use it again
    for line in lines:
        print line
```